# Get All Tables from All Databases with mysql

Tags: mysql

I want it some thing like that to get all tables from all databases

```
 select * from *
```

is it possible to do it

Comment: `SHOW TABLES FROM databasename`

Comment: but he wants to get all the values i guess from all the databases.

Answer (score 1):

This take all table from all database:

```
SELECT table_schema,TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES 
ORDER BY table_schema
```

`TABLE_SCHEMA` is database name.